# How to achieve assertDictEqual with assertSequenceEqual applied to values

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I know that, when performing `assertEqual` on a dictionary, `assertDictEqual` is called.  Similarly, `assertEqual` on a sequence will perform `assertSequenceEqual`.

However, when `assertDictEqual` is comparing values, it appears not to make use of `assertEqual`, and thus `assertSequenceEqual` is not called.

Consider the following simple dictionaries:

```
lst1 = [1, 2]
lst2 = [2, 1]

d1 = {'key': lst1}
d2 = {'key': lst2}

self.assertEqual(lst1, lst2) # True
self.assertEqual(d1, d2) # False ><
```

How can I test dictionaries such as `d1` and `d2` such that their equality is properly compared, by recursively applying `assertEqual`-like semantics to values?

I want to avoid using external modules (as suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491164/python-unittest-asserting-dictionary-with-lists)) if at all possible, unless they are native django extensions.

---

EDIT

Essentially, what I am after is a built in version of this:

```
def assertDictEqualUnorderedValues(self, d1, d2):
    for k,v1 in d1.iteritems():
        if k not in d2:
            self.fail('Key %s missing in %s'%(k, d2))

        v2 = d2[k]

        if isinstance(v1, Collections.iterable) and not isinstance(v1, basestring):
            self.assertValuesEqual(v1, v2)
        else:
            self.assertEqual(v1, v2)
```

The problem with the above code is that the error messages are not as nice as the builtin asserts, and there's probably edge cases I've ignored (as I just wrote that off the top of my head).

Comment: With the `unittest` module, `self.assertEqual(lst1, lst2)` isn't True --> `AssertionError: Lists differ: [1, 2] != [2, 1]`.

Comment: @martineau - my mistake; I misread that part of the documentation.  I am looking for an equivalent of `assertItemsEqual` rather than `assertSequenceEqual`

Comment: Well, if you make `lst1` and `lst2` the same so the first `assertEqual` succeeds, then the second one will, too.

Comment: The part about "looking for an equivalent of `assertItemsEqual` rather than `assertSequenceEqual`" makes no sense to me. My point was that the code in your question is using `assertEqual` on two lists with items in a different order and that assertion will fail.

Comment: If you control the code creating the datastructures, maybe you should use sets instead of lists.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than overriding assertDictEqual, why don't you recursively sort your dicts first?

```
def deep_sort(obj):
    """
    Recursively sort list or dict nested lists
    """

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        _sorted = {}
        for key in sorted(obj):
            _sorted[key] = deep_sort(obj[key])

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        new_list = []
        for val in obj:
            new_list.append(deep_sort(val))
        _sorted = sorted(new_list)

    else:
        _sorted = obj

    return _sorted
```

Then sort, and use normal assertDictEqual:

```
    dict1 = deep_sort(dict1)
    dict2 = deep_sort(dict2)

    self.assertDictEqual(dict1, dict2)
```

This approach has the benefit of not caring about how many levels deep your lists are.

Comment: `Exception: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`

Comment: Does not work for none inside of a list

Answer (score 5):

The `TestCase.assertEqual()` method calls the class' `assertDictEqual()` for `dicts`, so just override that in your subclass derivation. If you only use other `assertXXX` methods in the method, the error messages should be almost as nice as the built-in asserts -- but if not you can provide a `msg` keyword argument when you call them to control what is displayed.

```
import collections
import unittest

class TestSOquestion(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass # whatever...

    def assertDictEqual(self, d1, d2, msg=None): # assertEqual uses for dicts
        for k,v1 in d1.iteritems():
            self.assertIn(k, d2, msg)
            v2 = d2[k]
            if(isinstance(v1, collections.Iterable) and
               not isinstance(v1, basestring)):
                self.assertItemsEqual(v1, v2, msg)
            else:
                self.assertEqual(v1, v2, msg)
        return True

    def test_stuff(self):
        lst1 = [1, 2]
        lst2 = [2, 1]

        d1 = {'key': lst1}
        d2 = {'key': lst2}

        self.assertItemsEqual(lst1, lst2) # True
        self.assertEqual(d1, d2) # True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
> python unittest_test.py
.
---------------------------------------------------------------------->
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

>
```

Comment: I cannot guarantee the order of the lists.  The tests are for a django framework, and I can't rely on the order of database queries being the same between the test set and the expected result.  All I care about is that the API is giving me the correct values in *some* order.

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand why/how you expect the first `assertEqual(lst1, lst2)` to be True in your code.

Comment: This solution does not work on deeply nested dicts + lists. The solution based on sorting does.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i had to test if the fields of a model where correct. And MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names() sometimes returns ['a','b'] and sometimes ['b','a'].

When i run:

```
self.assertEqual(MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names(), ['a', 'b'])
```

it sometimes fails.

I solved it by putting both values in a set():

```
self.assertEqual(set(MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names()), set(['a', 'b'])) #true

self.assertEqual(set(MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names()), set(['b', 'a'])) #true
```

This will not work (returns True) with:

```
self.assertEqual(set(['a','a','b','a']), set(['a','b']))  # Also true
```

But since i'm checking for field names of a model , and those are unique, this is good by me.

Comment: You could use set notation to improve this, instead of `set(['a','b'])` try `{'a','b'}`.  Also, there is a function `self.assertSetEqual({'a','a','b','a'}, {'a','b'})` which will check the difference between the two sets and fail if they do not contain exactly the same elements.